# showManageSubscriptions(in:) crash app when the manager subscription view is close

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using the showManageSubscriptions(in:) function to show the iOS native subscription manager screen. It shows the subscription manager screen and lets me make changes to the subscription, but when I close the Subscription Manager view the app crash. How can I close the Subscription Manager View and show the view controller that is behind it without the app crashing?

I am using Xcode 13.4.1 and swift 5.5

Apple Documentation for showManagerSubscription(in:)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var managerBtn: UIButton!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    managerBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(manageSubscription), for: .touchUpInside)
}


@MainActor
@objc func manageSubscription() async throws {
    
    // if var  window = self.view.window?.windowScene {
    
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
        
        do {
            
            try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window  )
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}}
```

[This is how the error looks in Xcode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y01QM.png)